# Glide clear not working in onDestroyFragment()

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-glide

I relaized that I have memory leaks in my Fragment. So I made null the `views` in `onDestroyView` and memory consumption decreased a little. Then I wanted to also clear Glide memory with this:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();

    Glide.get(getContext()).clearMemory();
}
```

But as far as i can see nothing changed(I used Profiler to see memory consumption). So then I tried this:

```
Glide.with(getContext()).clear(my_profile_image);
```

But this time I got NullPointerException. My Glide load code:

```
Glide.with(getContext()).load(response.body().getProfileimage())
                                .dontAnimate()
                                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
                                .circleCrop()
                                .signature(new ObjectKey(response.body().getLastupdate()))
                                .into(my_profile_image);

                    }
```

So how can I clear Glide memory in `onDestroyView()` to decrease memory consumption ?

**Note:** Memory consumption is jumping from 20MB to 50MB when I remove and reopen Fragment quickly several times.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {

   Glide.get(getContext()).clearMemory();

   super.onDestroyView();
}
```

Try writing `clearMemory` before super call.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but still memory consumption is increasing. It's jumping from 20MB to 50MB when I remove and reopen Fragment quickly several times.

Comment: Maybe your memory leaks are related to something else. Did you check LeakCanary? What classes Android studio profiler is showing? Maybe you use retained fragment. It is not likely it is because of Glide library as it is very mature.

Comment: @Angelina I have just started to use LeakCanary and it indicated there are leaks for Views. So simply I made null my views in` onDestroyView()` and warnings disappeared. Yes memory consumption decreased a little. But still memory usage is increasing when I close Fragment and reopen.

Comment: You don’t need to make views null in onDestroyView as this should happen by itself. Try memory profiler. There you can order by class and see which ones take more memory

Comment: Do you store your fragment in a variable somewhere? Like in a ViewModel for example... this could be an issue

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler#record-allocations

Comment: @Angelina no I don't store fragment in a variable somewhere for now.